# Listview headerView and pull to refresh - android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview

I am using [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) library to add pull to refresh implementation to my app, and my app's listview also contains a headerview or a listheader view `list.addHeaderView(headerView);`

But I get an error `The method addHeaderView(View) is undefined for the type PullToRefreshListView`

Maybe the class does not exist? :0 or is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

considering list as instance of PullToRefreshListFragment/PullToRefreshListView

try this:

```
list.getRefreshableView().addHeaderView(headerView);
```

Answer (score 2):

The method addHeaderView is not available in the class PullToRefreshListView. You have to use something else. You need to add the header to an actual ListView as below:

```
final PullToRefreshListView v = (PullToRefreshListView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.list);
v.setOnRefreshListener(this);
final ListView lv = v.getRefreshableView();
TextView view = mRoot.findViewById(R.id.text);
lv.addHeaderView(view);
```